# How to split columns into dataframes that contain a column from the original dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want this input (dataframe **sampledata**):

| sample1 | sample2 | sample3 | sample4 | sample5 | species |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 0 | A. thaliana |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 1 | E. coli |

To this output:

| sample1 | species |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | A. thaliana |
| 2 | E. coli |

| sample2 | species |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | A. thaliana |
| 1 | E. coli |

for every table, so I have 5 dataframes. I would:

1. `sample1df <- sampledata$sample1` then
2. `sample1df <- cbind(sample1df, sampledata$species)` then
3. repeat for each sample.

Is there a more efficient or clean way?

Answer (score 2):

If your dataframe is df then

```
dframes <- lapply(1:5, function(x) df[ , c(x, 6)])
```

or generalize:

```
ncols <- ncol(df)
n <- ncols - 1
dframes <- lapply(1:n, function(x) df[ , c(x, ncols)])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can loop over the 'sample' column names, `select` that column along with 'species' in a `loop` and store the output in a `list`

```
nm1 <- grep('sample', names(df1), value = TRUE)
lst1 <- lapply(nm1, function(nm) df1[c(nm1', 'species')])
```

NOTE: This will pick up the 'sample' columns even if it is at any location.  So, the generalization is actually happening here

Answer (score 1):

very basic
base R subset and select

```
sample1df <- subset(sampledata, select = c(1, 6))
sample2df <- subset(sampledata, select = c(1, 5))
sample3df <- subset(sampledata, select = c(1, 4))
sample4df <- subset(sampledata, select = c(1, 3))
sample5df <- subset(sampledata, select = c(1, 2))
```